# Badge total not updating

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

According to my recent activity and profile page (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/21/chrisf) I've been awarded three badges, but the total on the summary is still saying 2.

In addition I've [answered a question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/187/how-do-i-delete-my-gmail-account/188#188) (admittedly my own) and received a couple of upvotes, but no Teacher badge - "Answered first question with at least one up vote".

Has something gone wrong with the badge system?

**UPDATE** I've just got a few more badges, so things might be working again. However, I didn't get the "Self Learner" badge for [the same answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/187/how-do-i-delete-my-gmail-account/188#188).

Nope still broken. Now I've got 6 badges but only 5 on the top of the page.

Comment: Lagging for me as well - I have 9 badges, page top says 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed and working.

<sup>Answer added so I can accept it and stop the Community user bumping it in the future)</sup>

Comment: +1 for giving the community user a well deserved break ;)